# Confusion on App ID and Bundle ID

Tags: xcode, bundle-identifier

I'm a bit confused after reading a post from 4 years ago regarding the Apple ID and Bundle ID. I was told by someone with a very high reputation score that the Apple ID and Bundle ID are the same. But according to the post I read they aren't.

*****The ***possible duplicate*** question is the question that confused me. My question has to do with whether or not the App ID and Bundle ID are the same, and if that means I have full access to my code. That doesn't seem clear to me in the question from 4 years ago. Things may have also been updated.

My question also has to do with only seeing info.developersname.appname and not com.???.???

I had a company that has since disappeared develop my Demeters Harvest app. I am now working on trying to learn the basics before going with a new developer and I am confused about how to gain access to the XCode so a new dev can update the app that has some glitches.

When I go into my portal I see three provisioning files for the app with the same App ID: info.OLDDEVELOPERNAME.demeter. One is with XC in front and then there's a Wild Card too.

Are none of these the bundle that lets me work on my app? I don't know if these mean I do have the bundle or not.

Thanks.

Comment: I updated the reason this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your confusion. The Bundle ID and the App ID have to match, but they are not in fact the same thing. The App ID is what is in iTunes Connect, the Bundle ID is what is found in your app (Xcode project). You can't change your App ID once your app is in the store, and since your Bundle ID has to match your App ID to release your app, they are sometimes referred to as the same.

If you create a new project, you can set your Bundle ID to the App ID in the iTunes Connect, and it will be accepted by iTunes Connect.

EDIT: Picture of where to find accepted Bundle ID in iTunes Connect.

[image]

Comment: That sounds incredibly easy. I don't lose anything by doing that?

Comment: No, if your are pushing your Xcode project to iTunes Connect it will be accepted as long as the Bundle ID matches your iTunes Connect ID. You can see the Bundle ID that will be accepted if you log into iTunes Connect, select the App, click on More, and Select About this App. You will see Bundle ID there, and that is what your Xcode project Bundle ID has to match.

Comment: Thank you! :) That is great to know and relieves a bunch of stress.